# Deploying React app on Firebase returns 404 pages

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

Trying to deploy my react app on firebase. The app gets deployed, but when links are clicked, it returns a 404 page.

I already logged into Firebase through the cli. Used `firebase init`:

```
? What do you want to use as your public directory? build
? Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? Yes
? Set up automatic builds and deploys with GitHub? No
? File build/index.html already exists. Overwrite? No
```

With `npm start` the application runs perfectly normal, but once I `npm run build` into `firebase init` and `firebase deploy`, it returns the login page properly, **but the other pages** are returned as 404 pages.

[image: 404page]

Firebase.json:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**My solution:**

So the problem was that `/home` got a 404 page. But it didn't when I used `firebase serve`. What I did was do the steps again and made sure the `build` files were all valid by running `npm start` into `npm run build`. Than I deployed it again and when I got the 404 page, I just refreshed and after that it's been working ever since.

Might have something to do with the deployment needing time to route everything properly, I'm not sure. But refreshing the 404 page did the trick for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

**try :**

copy code `index.html` outside "build" folder and paste into `index.html` inside "build" folder. ( the one inside should be the same as the other one)

**if it didn't work :**

1 -  delete your .firebase folder. and init it again using `firebase init`
and set the same configuration , then reload the website.